# Binomial distribution using MLE

Tags: mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution, likelihood

I have a few points in this binomial distribution given. Problem is that we find that out of $n=130$ people, $x=75$ of them play Minecraft.

We also find that in a population of $m_1 = 25$ men, $x_1 = 20$ men play Minecraft

We also find that in a population of $m_2 = 25$ women, $x_2 = 6$ women play Minecraft

I want to find $p_1$ (fraction of men playing Minecraft) and $p_2$ (fraction of women playing Minecraft) by writing a script and associated functions to find the MLEs of $p_1$ and $p_2$ using:

1. Alternating maximization using bisection to alternately find the maximum with respect to $p_1$ and with respect to $p_2$.
2. Multivariate Newton iteration
3. Multivariate method of scoring
4. Using R's nlm function

To implement these methods, you must write several functions involving the log likelihood for this
model. Their names and parameters are: p is a vector containing the parameters p1 and p2, and
n, m1, m2, x, x1, and x2 are scalars corresponding to the other quantities mentioned above:

```
log_likelihood <- function (p, n, m1, m2, x, x1, x2)

log_likelihood_gradient <- function (p, n, m1, m2, x, x1, x2)

log_likelihood_hessian <- function (p, n, m1, m2, x, x1, x2)

fisher_information <- function (p, n, m1, m2, x, x1, x2)
```

Use these functions to implement four functions for finding the MLE using the four methods mentioned
above, as follows:

```
mle_alt <- function (n,m1,m2,x,x1,x2,initial)

mle_mvn <- function (n,m1,m2,x,x1,x2,initial,iters)

mle_mos <- function (n,m1,m2,x,x1,x2,initial,iters)

mle_nlm <- function (n,m1,m2,x,x1,x2,initial)
```

here is the likelihood model given:
[image]

Comment: "To implement these methods, you must write several functions involving the log likelihood for this model" ... this is an exercise for a class, right? Otherwise how does the "you must" arise? Indeed the sudden change from "I want" to "you must" phrasing looks rather like an incomplete attempt to disguise that situation.

Comment: I was about to replace the image at the end with relevant MathJax markup (which would make it easier to read -- or even *possible*, for vision impaired users using screen readers) but I decided to leave the original there because it appears to contain an error and didn't want to make it look like I'd introduced one by accident.

Comment: Please read the self-study tag wiki info: https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and amend accordingly (i.e. add the tag, be explicit about the source of the question, show a proper attempt, etc etc)

Comment: It'd also be real nice if you stated what your question was.